# How to turn on block or panel from old site to the new one

Tags: views, nodes

I'm fairly new to Drupal. I have an old version of site with a "block" or "panel" or whatever it's called, that displays on a page, and the new version doesn't have it, and I for god's love can't figure out how to turn it on. It would require looking at it directly, because it's just something I can't see in that beautiful user friendly admin dashboard of Drupal.

EDIT: Upon closer examination, it looks like a view with "content" data that is on the old site, but the "content" is missing on new one. Anyone knowing how to deal with that, I would appriciate that a lot.

Comment: Export the view from old site and import in new site.. Are they (Old Site & New Site) using same Major Version of Drupal ?

Comment: Yes, thats great, how do I export it / import it. THere's not export import button there mate.

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using ? Are you logged in as admin ?

Comment: Hi there mate, yes I am. It's 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Views out of the box support export / import functionality . You can export any view from any instance to any instance using below steps.. Make sure both the instances are in same Major Drupal version..

- Login as administrator
- Go to the view you want to export "admin/structure/views"
- Edit View
- Click on export link in the drop down

[image]

- Copy content
- Go to new site and navigate to "admin/structure/views/import"
- Paste copied content and click on Import

[image]